# Including static image does not work in R/exams

Tags: r, moodle, figure, r-exams

I tried to adapt the `Rlogo.Rmd` exercise from R/exams but the inclusion of the statitic image does not work. It does not appear in Moodle or HTML and I don't see what I am missing. The Rmd for my question is:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", out.width = "20%"}
exams::include_supplement("dominio8a.png",dir="C:/Users/user/Dropbox/ISCA/MQ/testes/exercicios")
```

Question
========
A figura
\
![a]("dominio8a.png") representa o seguinte conjunto de pontos
do plano cartesiano:
    
Answerlist
----------
* $\{(x,y)\in R^2\;:\; x^2+y^2\leq 9\}$
* $\{(x,y)\in R^2\;:\; x^2+y^2= 9 \}$
* $\{(x,y)\in R^2\;:\; x^2+y^2< 9 \}$
* $\{(x,y)\in R^2\;:\; x^2+y^2\geq 9\}$

Meta-information
================
exname: T5_04
extype: schoice
exsolution: 1000
exshuffle: 4
````

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left. If anything is still unclear please adapt the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not quote the file name inside the Markdown syntax, i.e., simply use `![a](dominio8a.png)` without quotes instead of `![a]("dominio8a.png")`.

*Additional remarks:*

- For better formatting I would also recommend not to continue the text in the same line as the image. I would probably use:

  ```
  A figura representa o seguinte conjunto de pontos do plano cartesiano:
  \
  ![a](dominio8a.png)
  ```
- I have also submitted the solution section of your Rmd because it didn't provide additional information over the `exsolution`. In such cases you don't need to duplicate the information. The solution section is really intended for explaining *why* a certain item is true or false.